# How can i get out of the authentication screen and shutdown?

Tags: system-installation, kali-linux, authentication

I decided to install linux ,dualbooted, on my laptop but ran in some issues . I installed several corrupt installs causing me to allocate most of my harddrive ,at least the parts that do not contain my windows partition.

Now to get rid of it I used kali on usb which worked well. On wanting to shutdown my system i accidently pressed the logout screen.
Which gives me an authentication screen to get back in ,authentication that i did not create since i am running a usb persistence option for kali.

And i cant shutdown the system because i get a "system policy prevents stopping the system when other users are logged in".

I tried just turning the power of ,but when it boots back up ,it immediatley goes back to the auth. screen of kali so i cant access my bios.
I also removed usb, to no avail...

How can i get out of this mess i got myself into and just boot windows again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toor was a valid password for root, so i was able to shutdown. Problem solved